# Why won't this compile?

Tags: java

The problem: Write a method called `printGrid` that accepts two integers as representing a number of rows and columns and prints a grid of integers from 1 to(rows*columns) in column major order. For example, the call `printGrid(4,6);`

```
1 5 9 13 17 21
2 6 10 14 18 22
3 7 11 15 19 23
4 8 12 16 20 24
```

//what i have so far
// First year of Computer Science, appreciate any help.

```
public class ThreeFive {

  public static void main(String[]args) {
    public static void printGrid(int row, int column) {
      for (int b =1; b<= row; i++) {
        for (int a=b; a <=row * column: j+4) {
          System.out.print(a+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On what line of code are you getting the compile error, and what is the exact wording of the error message you are receiving?

Comment: what error messages are you getting

Comment: maybe because you have a static method inside of main...

Answer (score 3):

replace colon with semicolon in inner the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
 column:
```

Need a semicolon.

```
 column;
```

Also, you can't have methods nested within other methods.

Comment: So how do I declare the printGrid method? Where would I put it?

Comment: Put it outside as part of the `ThreeFive` class

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have a method inside a method.

Try:

```
public class ThreeFive{

  public static void main(String[]args){
      for (int b =1; b<= row; b++){
        for (int a=b; a <=row * column; a++){
            System.out.print(a+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This bit still doesn't compile: `int b =1; b<= row; i++`. And symbol `j` in `j+4` also doesn't resolve.

Comment: You need to change the colon in the second loop to a semicolon as well :(

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was a bit blindsided there. It's fixed now :) It seemes the asked copy/pasted the code from someone else...

Answer (score 0):

You have a method defined in the body of another method.  Thats not legal unless you are defining something like a lambda.  Move your printGrid method outside of main.  Also you haven't declared i or j, and you use a colon where you should have used a semicolon.